# Add a value when clicked button javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add value 1 when button was clicked and 0 when i am not clicking the button.
But when the web is first loaded it is set to the value 0.
I write my code like this

```js
function cek(){
    if(document.getElementById('historyBtn').clicked == true ){
        return 1
    } else{
        return 0
    }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="historyBtn" class="btn btn-round btn-outline btn-default" >History Messages</button>
```

But when i click button `historyBtn` the value always 0

Comment: do you have a variable that you need to set the value?

Comment: Please explain when you call the function cek();

Comment: are you trying to build a counter?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get the word `value` you are saying.

I will assume it is a variable in your JS.

You can just use `onclick`.

```
<button type="button" id="historyBtn" onclick="buttonClicked()" class="btn btn-round btn-outline btn-default" >History Messages</button>
```

```
var theValue = 0;
function buttonClicked() {
    theValue = 1;
}
```